# how to parse HTML in android and execute javascript

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, html-parsing, jsoup, htmlunit

I am trying to figure out how to parse HTML where I should execute javascript.

I was trying a lot of way to do that, but still have nothing

For example:

> - HTMLUnit - seems to me like the best parser to execute javascript, but when I try to add dependencies getting error, that haven't solved in stackoverflow
> - Selenium Web Driver. Also looks good, but again a lot of problem with dependencies. And cannot find any examples of that
> - Rhino. Very limited documentation about integration in android
> - JSoup. Pretty good, but cannot execute javascript

I will be very thankful who will try me to figure out how to parse HTML with javascript with some examples. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should think of using [Appium](http://appium.io/) to parse your HTML webpages on Android.  Appium is an extension of Selenium Webdriver providing automation capabilities on Android and iOS.

You can get started from this link: [How to setup Appium Environment for Android Automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861998/how-to-setup-appium-environment-for-android-automation)

Also, you can execute javascript using appium driver:

```
js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("<JAVASCRIPT CODE>");
```

Comment: Cool. I have some experience with Appium testing. Do you have any examples or articles how to parse HTML with Appium?

Comment: You can use xpath, css, and other locator strategies provided by Appium to parse html and get the values out of HTML

Comment: For some examples refer: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/selenium-locators

Comment: Did you try to parse HTML with Appium?

Comment: please explain your definition of "parse" html

Comment: I mean, that I have site that don't have API, so I need to parse HTML to get all data from site

Comment: hmm, i am only able to  vaguely understand your requirement. try getPageSource() metiond of driver: https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getPageSource--

Comment: do you understand what I wanna do?\